# Looping over nested object

Tags: java, jackson

I am working with Jackson to parse json data into a series of nested objects in Java.

I then need to loop over some of the nested objects and want to know if you can access a list of nested objects for looping directly.

Currently I can only access the nested objects/nested lists by nesting for loops.

`RootNode` has a `List<VisibleEntities>` which in turn has a `Dto`. Dto has a `List<Segments>` which has a attribute String transfer .

Looks a bit like this:

[image]

Currently I access this by:

```
        for (VisibleEntities v: rootNode.visibleEntities) {
            for (Segments s: v.dto.segments) {
                if (s.transfer != null) {
                    System.out.println(s.transfer.getName());
                }
            }
       }
```

Is there a way to loop over rootNode.visibleEntities.dto.segments and print dto.segments.transfer (if not null) directly?

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like `dto` is not an array or list?

Comment: “Is there a way to loop over rootNode.visibleEntities and print dto.timeSpan if not null directly?” — I don’t understand this question: can’t you literally do exactly that? Where is the issue?

Comment: Is reflection allowed and do you have to print specific fields or all of them? Also, what are you trying to solve other than "nested loops"?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is structured as a nested loop then you're going to need to iterate through both loops. You can apply some Java8 streaming if you want to shorten it though.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NestedStreamTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Following is for example data
    var nest = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      nest.add(list);
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        if(j % 2 == 0)
          list.add(j);
        else
          list.add(null);
    }
    
    //Actual looping starts here
    nest.stream() //Loop through the nest
      .flatMap(list -> list.stream()) //Loop through each list in the nest
      .filter(value -> value != null) //Only allow values which are not null to continue
      .forEach(value -> System.out.println(value.toString())); //Print each filtered value
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question to better reflect the data. Dto is not a list, however the principles of the question are the same. It appears the answer is that nested for statements are needed.

Comment: @AlGrant Fraid so. If that is the way the data is structured then that's the way it needs handled. There are options to streamline the looping if you want to minimize code, as this example shows.

Comment: Sometimes v.dto.segments is null. How could this be handled?

Comment: @AlGrant Depends on what you mean by handled. If you want those values to be skipped, then I already have that in my example with the `.filter(v -> v != null)` portion of the stream which filters out any null values before passing the remaining values to the `forEach` portion.

Comment: @AlGrant I've updated the example with comments to better explain what each step is doing.